# How to update PATH in GitHub Actions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, github-actions

I'm trying to update the path variable in Linux VM in GitHub CI.

What I'm trying are:

- `export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/bin"`
- `export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/bin:$PATH`

But nothing seems to working, as when I'm trying to `echo`, it doesn't return me what I was expecting. What it lists is:

```
/home/runner/.local/bin
/opt/pipx_bin
/home/runner/.cargo/bin
/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin
/usr/local/.ghcup/bin
/home/runner/.dotnet/tools
/snap/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

It should have contained (or at least something like this):

```
/usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/bin
```

Full job details: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/unmukto/actions/runs/3590283087/jobs/6043518013

Comment: why not installing that with the related action, like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-android-sdk-tools

Comment: @Matteo thanks Sir, that's a nice alternative... but I'm trying to learn more about 'pipeline', that's why I'm experimenting... and trying to learn... (trial error)* success... maybe...

Answer (score 4):

It *does* get added to the `$PATH`, but you can't use it in subsequent steps because GitHub Actions isolates steps from one another. If you ran `sdkmanager --version` **in the same step** that you update the `$PATH` in, it would work. Use the GitHub Actions syntax for [Adding a system path](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path) to append to `$GITHUB_PATH`, which will automatically persist your edit across the rest of steps in the job:

> Prepends a directory to the system PATH variable and automatically makes it available to **all subsequent actions** in the current job; the currently running action **cannot** access the updated path variable.

An abbreviated version of your `build.yml` using `$GITHUB_PATH`:

```yaml
name: build Android

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Exporting android sdk'    
      run: echo "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: 'Download and extract android-cli tools'    
      run: |
        curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-9123335_latest.zip --output commandlinetools-linux-9123335_latest.zip
        sudo mkdir /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
        sudo unzip -o commandlinetools-linux-9123335_latest.zip -d /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
    - name: 'Exporting android-cli (sdkmanager) ,'    
      run: echo "${{ env.ANDROID_SDK_ROOT }}/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Also note how instead of `export`ing `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, it's added to the `$GITHUB_ENV` and accessed in a subsequent step with `${{ env.ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}}`.